# how to convert negative number to binary and vice versa?

Tags: c++, audio, binary, bitset, wave

I have this audio file which I transformed it's audio values to binary numbers so that I hide them in image pixels.

what I used to convert the audio values was bitset<16> since the audio values are stored in short int variables.

the conversion to binary works well even if its a negative number but the conversion from the negative binary value to decimal is not working so does any one know a suitable way to convert negative binary numbers to decimal.

```
bitset <16>a = -8;
cout<<a<<endl;
output = 1111 1111 1111 1000

bitset <16>b = 8;
cout<<b<<endl;
output = 0000 0000 0000 1000
// but if i tried to convert the binary that i got earlier from the -8
bitset <16> c = 1111111111111000;
cout<< c.to_ulong()<<endl;
output = 29016
// how can i get the output of -8 from the c?
```

Comment: Pop quiz: what number is 1111111111111000? Why do you think it should be -8?

Comment: the only reason I think so is because this is the output that I got from cout<<a<<endl and for the number I read some stuff about the conversions between binary to decimal and the negative parts and one complement and two's complements but honestly I didn't understand them very well and I didn't use a lot of time for it because I was trying to find the code that does it. and this is probably because of the two's complement

Comment: If you write: `int n=1111111111111000`, do you really think you'll wind up with -8 in the variable? Of course not.

Comment: Is this `1000` an eight or a thousand? You cannot answer. The compiler reads by the syntax rules and decided that it is a thousand. Now compare that to `c = 1111111111111000`. What do you expect the compiler to do?

Comment: hmm I read the explanation again after your comment and I got it so to represent -8 I go through these steps if am using 16 bit then 8 is 0000 0000 0000 1000 to make it negative I need to inverse first which is this 1111 1111 1111 0111 then add a complement i don't know how to do the last part

Comment: so how do I get the value of the decimal number @SamVarshavchik

Comment: When you write `int n=10;`, do you expect to wind up with 10, or 2, in the variable `n`. Of course it's 10. When you write a number in C++ code, it is interpreted as an ordinary base 10 number, always was, always will be. Doesn't matter how big or small it is. End of story.

Comment: thank you for the explanation and sorry for being a bit slow but please bear with me for a while longer. just now you said that when I write a number um I had a counter to count the number of bits in the audio file that counter when I print the value it was  147456 when I use bitset <16> to print it I get the binary representation and when I use the to_ulong() I get 147456 again. so what you mean by write is if I wrote the number manually by myself? and if so how do I mimic this for negative numbers?or is it already mimicking it and the only problem was that I tried to test this manually?@SamV